# Converting some values of a json string to an integer in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following php code:

```
$data = array(
'id' => $_POST['id'],
'name' => $_POST['name'],
'country' => $_POST['country'],
'currency' => $_POST['currency'],
'description' => $_POST['description']
);

$data_string = json_encode($data);
```

The sample JSON is as follows:

```
{
 "id":"7",
 "name":"Dean",
 "country":"US",
 "currency":"840",
 "description":"Test"      
}
```

I need to make the "id" field an integer only and keep "currency" as a string so that the JSON becomes this:

```
 {
 "id":7,
 "name":"Dean",
 "country":"US",
 "currency":"840",
 "description":"Test"      
}
```

I tried using:

```
$data_string = json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

But it also turns "currency" to an integer.

Is there any way that I can make "id" an integer and leave currency as a string.

Comment: try my answer to solve your problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Type casting` like

```
$data = array(
'id' => (int) $_POST['id'],// type cast
'name' => $_POST['name'],
'country' => $_POST['country'],
'currency' => $_POST['currency'],
'description' => $_POST['description']
);

$data_string = json_encode($data);
```